# How to install curl from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile

I'm trying to install curl on my Docker container to use it in a health check, but I can' seem to get it to install by running commands in the Dockerfile. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y curl
WORKDIR /app
COPY /Project.MyProject .
RUN dotnet publish -o /publish
WORKDIR /publish
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "dotnet Project.MyProject.dll \"${DB_CONNECTION}\""]
```

Then when I run any `curl` command from inside the container by first doing `docker exec it` then it tells me `curl not found`. If I run `apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl` when the container is up and running then curl installs just fine. How can I get curl to install by running commands in the Dockerfile? I would like to avoid having to install it manually after the container is up and running.

Comment: I created a docker image using your Dockerfile and do not have the problem using curl in container. Was the 2nd step ```RUN apt-get update \ && apt-get install -y curl``` of Dockerfile while building docker image successful? I.e. not throwing any warning or something?

Answer (score 7):

I just tested the RUN apt-get update 
&& apt-get install -y curl  line and it works well.

Look at how i did it,

Define a stage with .NET core image as base, which will end up being used as final image.

Define an other stage based on dotnet SDK image as build in order to build and publish the application, then reuse the base image as the final image.

Here's my dockerfile which works fine for building and packaging dotnet apps while installing packages like curl and jq.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl jq 
    
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src


COPY ["PROJECT.csproj", "project/"]

RUN dotnet restore "project/project.csproj" 
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"

RUN dotnet build "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

RUN dotnet test "../project.Test" \ 
    /p:CollectCoverage=true \ 
    /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover \ 
    /p:CoverletOutput="./../coverage" \
    /p:Include=\"[project.BLL]*,[project.Model]*\"

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]


You can see that the final image is the one that depends on the base image with installed curl and jq
```

Please tick the answer if it helped you !

Comment: Worked great! I made sure `WORKDIR` matched in `base` and `final`, and I didn't need `jq` so just adding curl worked: `RUN apt-get update \ && apt-get install -y curl`